# Put request returns original data

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, restful-url

Hi I am really new to Javascript backend.  I would appreciate some help here.  I have the following model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
*const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create to store user favs
const FavsSchema = new Schema({
  userName: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  programId : { type : Array, default: [] }
});

module.exports = UserFavs = `mongoose.model('favorites', FavsSchema);*`
```

I am trying to make a put request using the following code

```
/* PUT /userName/:id */
  router.put('/postData/:user_id', function (req, res, next) {
      UserFavs.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, req.body, {new: true}).then(function(){
        console.log('is it valid')
        console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.user_id))
          UserFavs.findOne({userName: req.params.user_id}).then(function(userfav){
            console.log(userfav)
          res.send(userfav)
        })
      })
    })
```

I call the API on a react front end where the user selects data from a data grid and presses a button to save their favorite programs

```
buttonTest2(dataArray2, userId) {
    axios.put('/api/favorites/postData/userId', this.dataArray2)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('put response', response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error is ', error);
    })
}
```

I am just getting the original data back.  I don't understand why this is happening.  Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
/* PUT /updateData/:id */
    router.put('/updateData/:user_id', 
      passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
      function (req, res) {
        let id = req.params.user_id;
        let update = req.body;
        UserFavs.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {programId: update}, {new: true}, function(err, userfav) {
          if(err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.json(userfav);
          }
      });
    });
```

Needed to read into the documentation.  you have to bind req.body to the model property of programId